After almost 40 years of research on space stations in LEO, what is there we still didn't find out?
The first modular space station Mir was launched in early 1986 into orbit, so the time of research on the Mir and the ISS (and the Tiangongs) combined is now more than 38 years. If you include Salyut 6 and 7, it's more than 46 years of LEO research. After all those years I'm curious what there still is we didn't find out on a LEO space station.
One example coming into my mind is that we could let someone spend a new duration record on the ISS, e.g. two years, as a preparation for a possible Mars mission. But is a new duration mission thought about? Other than that, what else is there we still might not have found out after decades of crew exchanges on LEO space stations? And if they're only for the purpose of Earth observation there: can crews on space stations do something Earth observation satellites can't?

Considering the diversity and complexity of experiments that exploit the microgravity laboratory environments available in large space stations, and the very limited success of completely automating them or equipping the ISS with anthropomorphic (or otherwise creepy looking) robots until now, I think that crewed space stations still yield science that uncrewed can't. However, that said, it seems that the not-so-distant future will bring potentially useful, and AI-driven anthropomorphic (or otherwise creepy looking) robots, it seems the end of the decade is perfect for private industry's turn

...to take over and to roboticize and otherwise automate science. How many robots have been at, in, or on the ISS? As for Earth observation - yes, as launch-to-orbit costs continue to plummet and the concept of just sticking one kind of instrument on to another kind of satellite (e.g. Earth imagers on communications satellites in GEO) those really don't need to have humans around them. It's just that in the past it's been at least perceived as easier and cheaper to stick them on to the outside of the ISS. (purely my opinion, so not an answer)

@uhoh I wonder what kind of experiments you describe in the first post still haven't been done after those 38+ years? People have been in microgravity laboratories for so long so I wonder what experiments still haven't been done respectively what new experiments are being done.

We did not yet find out how to make closed (or nearly closed)-loop life support systems to enable human exploration of the solar system.

Much of the life time of ISS and MIR the reliability was such that most time was spent on maintenance. Not an answer since do not have a source handy but a common statement is that anytime the ISS has only three crew on board little research gots done as all effort went into fixing, cleaning and repairing the structure of the station. So total 'science time' is well short of 40 years, closer to 'days when station crew > 3'. Meaning we may have a lot left to learn on building space stations.

@StarCaptain I don't see how "still haven't been done" applies to any research, anywhere. Nothing is ever "done" in science!

@GremlinWranger The ISS payloads utilization rate has increased significantly in the last decade. Fiscal years 2017, 2018, and 2019 saw 2390, 2820, and 2944 payload hours respectively.

I recently learned that 20% of the scientific papers produced from ISS experiments have come from one experiment: NICER. It's doesn't do life sciences, microgravity or Earth observation. It's a cluster of x-ray telescopes for astronomy.

Science never really stops; there's no point where we look at a topic, dust off our hands, and say "Well, we know absolutely everything about this, time to move on!"
Now, you could argue that telepresence has come a long way in the last couple of decades and we could likely replace people with robots in a lot of contexts, but there's a lot that a camera-with-arms can't do. Humans are simply too good at manipulating our environment to be completely replaced.
But that aside, one of the big ongoing questions that's been studied since the start and still has only partial answers (and isn't reasonably possible to research remotely) is how to get a human body to maintain decent physical condition while in zero gravity. We tackled bone and muscle loss early on, but there a lot of other issues that show up after weeks or months in orbit.  For example, there are a lot of weird fluid buildups -- sinuses don't drain correctly, cerebrospinal fluid shifts into the head, even the pressure inside eyeballs can change and cause blurry vision. We're still early-days in researching a lot of that, which is going to be required knowledge if we ever mean to have permanent space habitats (or at least the non-spinning type -- rotating habitats have a host of challenges of their own, both engineering and biological).

What about that Nautilus-X module they wanted to add to the ISS but cancelled it? Why is it so hard to attach or build a rotational gravity module? The point of such a module would be not to necessarily create Earth's gravity, but to create some low gravity (e.g. 0.38g like on Mars and Mercury) in order to test what you describe in a safer way. A module generating 0.38g doesn't need to be as large as a 1g module. Another possibility is a lunar habitat, where you'd have natural and low gravity. As for now, are there planned attempts to break Valery Polyakov's duration record?

As I understand it, ISS centrifuge tests were victim to budget cuts, but there are a few engineering difficulties as well - a big one is the added gyroscopic inertia makes rotating the station harder, and I would think there would be balancing issues, like when your dryer starts thumping. I'm not sure what the duration record question has to do with it.

The duration record question has got to do with your last paragraph about issues with the human body in microgravity. They sent up people for around a year to the ISS so now one wonders what would happen to the body if one was even longer in microgravity.

@StarCaptain Polyakov spent 437 continuous days on Mir.

@OrganicMarble Yes, that's the record. Are there any concepts to surpass it in the near future?

I don't think there are but that's a different question not related to the current discussion.
